# Control de estado de una bateria con python y raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Estoy buscando la forma de ver la carga de una batería en mi raspberry pi atravez de un LTC4151, y que salga un mensaje con la cantidad de porcentaje de carga. El problema es que no se como obtener ese dato. Aclaro que estoy usando python

Comment: Muestra qué has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Comment: El LTC4151 tiene interfaz I2C, y tiene librerías para interfaz con Arduino (C/C++). No encontré ninguna librería Python para el chip.

Comment: Gracias, yo tmb estuve buscando alguna librería con python pero no encontré tmp